# How to write Sql query by using groupby?

Tags: mysql

i want to write a query by using group by. It didn't help me.
my requirement is that i have a table you can see productId, makeId, modelId, yearId. I want to write a query that if makeId, modelId, and yearId same it will retun one record.

please check the below scrren which my table content having different product but makeId, modelId and yearId same. in that case it will return only one record those having same make, modle and year.

I have tried using groupby but i can't get the exact solution

[image]

```
SELECT * from rts_filter GROUP BY (rts_filter.makeId, rts_filter.modelId,  rts_filter.yearId);
```

**Output**

[image: dfd]

Thanks

Comment: At the very least include you query as code and not a screen shot... You also **must** include what you want as an output. We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

A way is based  ond the  use of  aggregation function eg: max or min  and group by

```
select  min(filterid), min(productid), makeid, modelid, yearid
from rts_filter 
group by makeid, modelid, yearid
```

or max

```
select  max(filterid), max(productid), makeid, modelid, yearid
from rts_filter 
group by makeid, modelid, yearid
```